# Como atualizar uma página depois de abrir uma nova janela

Tags: php, javascript, atualização

Eu tô com um problema e não sei como resolver, eu tô criando um sistema que quando você clica em um link o navegador abre uma nova janela.

Como nesse exemplo:

```html
<a href="link" target="_blank">Veja esse vídeo</a>
```

Quando o usuário entra no link ele é direcionado para uma nova janela no navegador e um cookie é definido para caso o usuário volte na página anterior ela esteja diferente.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['riu'])):
    header('Location: ../riu.php');
endif;
```

Mas para que esse código funcione a página precisa ser atualizada para reconhecer o cookie e redirecionar o usuário para outra página.

Então o que eu quero é que quando o usuário entre no link que abre o vídeo em outra janela, a página do link seja atualizada para que ele execute o script do cookie em php e redirecione pra página "riu.php".

Já tentei o segunte código:

```html
<a href="link" target="_blank" onclick="Location.reload()">Veja esse vídeo</a>
```

Mas como mostrado acima a página é atualizada sem abrir uma nova janela.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem a sua necessidade, você quer abrir a nova página, setar o cookie, e depois quer que **essa** página que seta o cookie atualize, ou a anterior, que o usuário estava?

Comment: Eu quero que a página anterior que o usuário estava seja atualizada na hora que o usuário entrar no link que vai abrir uma nova janela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não acredito que seja a melhor forma de fazer isso, porém funciona utilizando usando [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) após a abertura da página:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
        clearInterval(timer);  
        location.reload();
}, 100);
```

Para deixar as coisas mais práticas, criei uma função que faz isso com [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) que pega o atributo `href` do link:

```js
function abrirLink(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = $(event.target).attr('href');
      window.open(url);
      var timer = setInterval(function() {   
        clearInterval(timer);  
        location.reload();
      }, 100); 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://google.com" onclick="abrirLink(event)">Abrir</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Desta forma, basta colocar `onclick="abrirLink(event)"` nos links que deseja que tenha esse comportamento.

Também é possível omitir o `setInterval`, e atualizar a página logo após que a outra abrir:

```
function abrirLink(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var url = $(event.target).attr('href');
          window.open(url);
          location.reload();
}
```